# Cannot run php script from php script

Tags: php, apache

I make an web application which can submit form to database then create a text file in server. When after submit form (update.php) it will redirect to another html file but I'm very confused about how it will automatically run another php file to create a text file.

here is my update.php

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=index.php"> 
<body>
<?php
include 'connectdb.php';
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$name = $_POST["name"];                                                                                                                
$lastname =  $_POST["lastname"];  

//echo $name," ",$lastname;

$insertsql = "UPDATE user SET name ='$name', lastname='$lastname' ";

if($conn->query($insertsql) === TRUE){

echo "update ok";
}

else{
echo "Error :" . $insertsql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

exec('php build_conf.php');

?>
</body></head></html>
```

I have tried exec but it didn't work. It can UPDATE to database perfectly. but it can't run the build_conf.php file.
When I run command:

```
php build_conf.php
```

It works perfectly too.

This is build_con.php

```
<?php
include 'fetch_data.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$file_name = 'poll.conf';
$file_name_path = '/var/www/html/home/test_connect/'.$file_name;

$file_conn = fopen("$file_name_path","w") or die("Unable to open");
$DocumentRoot = "My name is ".$name."\n";
fwrite($file_conn, $DocumentRoot);
$Hill = "My lastname is ".$lastname."\n";
fwrite($file_conn, $Hill);
fclose($file_conn);
```

?>

these are all about test code.
It will be very great if you can help me :)

Comment: Are you sure you are on the right track here? The usual way with php web apps is to accept user input with your php script and if further processing is needed redirect to another url which of course is handled by another php script.

Comment: try to put the absolute path for your file **build_conf.php**
also show us the `var_dump();` :

`exec('php build_conf.php', $array, $code);
var_dump($array);
var_dump($code);`

Answer (score 0):

Just include the file:

```
include_once 'build_conf.php';
```

Additionally you can encapsulate it in a funtion:

```
function createFile(){}

    include 'fetch_data.php';

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $file_name = 'poll.conf';
    $file_name_path = '/var/www/html/home/test_connect/'.$file_name;

    $file_conn = fopen("$file_name_path","w") or die("Unable to open");
    $DocumentRoot = "My name is ".$name."\n";
    fwrite($file_conn, $DocumentRoot);
    $Hill = "My lastname is ".$lastname."\n";
    fwrite($file_conn, $Hill);
    fclose($file_conn);

}
```

And call it from update.php:

```
include_once 'build_conf.php';
createFile();
```